# Pass string parameter to SqlDataSource in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, sqldatasource

i have placed a SqlDataSource component on my aspx page but while configuring the SqlDataSource in the "Test Query" Step I am passing the following parameters :

[image]

But when i click ok it returns following error:

[image]

This error occurs when i pass the string :

INFO, WARN, ERROR,

I have tried a lot of combinations but nothing works. It works only if i pass one of the three words in single quotes like this :

'ERROR'

Infact the INFO WARN and ERROR are the various levels available in the table. Each record can have only one level  and in the sql query i am using IN("-----") to match the criteria, hope you understand.

Any idea to pass the string with comas between them will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved the problem by passing each level in single quotes without , after the last level as shown in  the image below:

[image]

Anyway thanks for your help Aristos!

Answer (score 1):

After you create the page with the dialogue helpers, just switch to code view of your html and change them by hand on the created code...

Comment: but the parameters are dynamically changed depending upon the selection made by the user so how to change them in html Can you kindly give some example.

Comment: @Rahat can you please type here the generated code to give you an example (if I can) on your code.

Comment: <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSourceLog" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:SmokeDBConString %>" 
        SelectCommand="qry_log" 
        SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure">
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="MaxRecords" Type="Int32" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Level" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="FromDate" DbType="DateTime"/>
            <asp:Parameter Name="ToDate" DbType="DateTime"/>
        </SelectParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>